# In Angular arrow function as member variable

Tags: angular, typescript, callback

Arrow function as member variable of class in Angular, this.chLocation.back() function doesn't work as expected when calling from callback function.

```
export class ChQuContactComponent {
    private chLocation  : Location;

    private chOnRemoved = () => {
        this.chLocation.back();
    }
    
    public chTest() {
        myCallBack(chOnRemoved);
    }
}
```

Thanks your help.

Comment: Why not  you use an event emitter or a subject instead callback

Comment: not me, the library that I use does it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass explicitly the scope where callback is gonna run:

myCallBack(chOnRemoved.bind(this));

Comment: thanks your reply.  But it is call the function immediately, not waits callbacks and also doesn't work (no backs).

Comment: I think I did a mistake, try .bind insted of .apply

Comment: I've understood, and already tried :)...  bu not works...  It works when I give it as a parameter, not a variable? what's the difference?

Comment: Need some more details to understand what is happening.

Comment: Yep, code is quite complex, and I can say; I am using Qt WebChannel js code.  So QObject has "connect" function for signals, and it works as callback function.  When I put the arrow function as parameter (not variable as defined in the class), it works !  but when I use as member variable doesn't work.  Signal handle ok, but Location.back doesn't work without any error etc.

Comment: It is very funny, when I move chOnRemoved function from class scope to function scope, it works !